# Equals has a different behaviour between string and nullable of int

Tags: c#

Why Equals has a different behaviour between string and nullable of int?

```
((int?)null).Equals(null)
```

This instruction return true

```
((String)null).Equals(null)
```

This instruction throw null is null

So, how to check on a KeyValuePair of (String, String) that the key is null

**Edit:**
I can't use String.IsNullOrEmpty because I use some List of KeyValuePair of (String, String)
and some List of KeyValuePair of (Int?, String)
where the key can be null or String.Empty
Exemple for a list to filter on a list of country :

```
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair(null, "Undefined"));
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair("", "Empty"));
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair("ID101", "France"));
myList.Add(new KeyValuePair("ID102", "Spain"));
```

Comment: [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: What does the sample code have to do with the actual question?

Comment: Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` perhaps?

Comment: What about `kvp.Key == null`? Also if it came from a dictionary the key can't be null.

Comment: And this, ladies and gentlemen, is why we should prefer `==` to `.Equals`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior in this case is different because `Nullable<T>` is a *value type* whereas a `String` is a *reference type*.

So this:

```
(int?)null
```

Actually has a value, since it's a value type. Thus you can call methods on it.

In any case, this is orthogonal to the bottom question, how to check if a KeyValuePair key of type string is null...

What about just:

```
if (kvp.Key == null)
```

If `null` should be treated the same way as `String.Empty`, you can use this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Key))
```

And if the key only contains whitespace (space, tab, linefeed, etc.) and this is also equivalent, you can use this:

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(kvp.Key))
```

Comment: "Thus you can call methods on it." - well, *some* methods - don't call `.GetType()` ;p Frankly, it would be nice if the compiler interpreted "call .GetType() on a value-typed expression" as simply "typeof(the expression)", since the type is *by definition* known to the compiler

Comment: Odd that it boxes the type in this case, but yes, valid point.

Answer (score 1):

((String)null)  at this point you've got a null - therefore .Equals doesn't exist.

String.IsNullOrEmpty() is used to test for a string which is null or equals string.Empty